# doctrine get OneToMany relation results

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I have 3 entities `Advert`, `Applications`, `ApplicationFiles`

`Advert`

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Application", mappedBy="advert", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $applications;
```

`Applications`

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ApplicationFiles", mappedBy="app", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $applicationFiles;
```

`ApplicationsFiles`

```
public function getFilePath(): string
    {
        return Uploader::APPLICATION_FILES.'/'.$this->getName();
    }
```

What I'm trying to do, is when I remove an Advert is to delete every `Application` with it's related `ApplicationsFiles` - which I did

My problem is that i can't manage to get the file names for each `Advert` so i could delete them.

All I could manage to do is to get only one result ...

```
$appRepo = $m->getRepository(Application::class);
$rrr = $appRepo->getFilePath($post);
    dd($rrr);
```

`getFilePath`

```
/**
 * @param $s
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getFilePath($s)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->andWhere('advert.id = :s')
        ->leftJoin('a.applicationFiles','applicationFiles')
        ->leftJoin('a.advert','advert')
        ->addSelect('applicationFiles.name')
        ->setParameter('s', $s)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
        ;
}
```

Dump -

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
0 => Application^ {#1186 ▶}
"name" => "hrm-01-application-5db552d60410c.doc"
 ]
]
```

Any help would be very appreciated :)

Comment: the `createQueryBuilder($alias)` of a repository by default calls `->select('EntityClass '.$alias)` and `->from('EntityClass '.$alias)`. now if you, instead of `addSelect` just call `select` (overwriting the first implicit select), you should get an array of file names. I might be wrong though, in that case, create a clean query builder via: `$this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()->from(Application:.class, 'a')`...

Comment: the ``select`` works, i get all the results, now i can't ``implode`` the output to ``$this->filesystem->delete(self::APPLICATION_FILES.'/'.$file);``

Comment: what would you implode? oO

Comment: this is the array i'm getting from ``$appRepo->getFilePath($post);``

``array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "name" => "hrm-01-application-5db552d60410c.doc"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "name" => "fac-em-5db68af84036f.pdf"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "name" => "27-sonde-3e-5db68afe97137.xls"
  ]
]``

i'm trying to send it to ``$this->filesystem->delete(self::APPLICATION_FILES.'/'.$file);`` which returns boolean

Comment: I mean ... yeah, you get an array of arrays with key 'name' so ... `foreach($appRepo->getFilePath($post) as $arr) { $this->filesystem->delete(...$arr['name']); }` however, to be honest, you should have a look at doctrine events (the delete on a application file entity could trigger the filesystem delete) and cascade deletes on the relations from adverts to applications to application files. maybe even orphanremoval as well.

Comment: Warning: Only arrays and Traversables can be unpacked ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201487/discussion-between-jakumi-and-alexander-br).

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you should query not `Applications` entity, but `ApplicationFiles`! Then you will get array of files to delete.

```php
$filesToDelete = $m->getRepository(ApplicationsFiles::class)
                   ->createQueryBuilder('af')
                   ->innerJoin('af.application', 'a')
                   ->innerJoin('a.advert','advert')
                   ->andWhere('advert.id = :s')
                   ->setParameter('s', $post)
                   ->getQuery()
                   ->getReqult();
```

I'm not sure about `$post` var is it `ID` or `Advert` object? If it's object then we can remove second join and use only join with `Application` entity.